# Edwardian Script to Text In HTML5

Tags: css, html, font-family

I have to display the text with font family as `Edwardian Script`.

How to do that?

This is my html:

```
<div class="sweetest_ride">Sweetest Rides Available Worldwide</div>
```

This is css:

```
.sweetest_ride {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    font-family: "Edwardian Script";
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

When i using this nothing wiil happen.

The Edwardian Script font family is displayed in this link:

[www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=990](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=990)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a [`@font-face` rule in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-face-rule):

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "Edwardian Script";
    src: url(path/to/the/font);
}
```

and then use it with:

```css
font-family: "Edwardian Script";
```

See the supplied link for more information on parameters that can be set.

Answer (score 1):

The full font name is "Edwardian Script ITC". It works for me whenever I use it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this :

```
body {
    font-family: "Edwardian Script ITC";
}
```